# Simple Progressive bar connecting values with C# code

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a simple  progressive bar in my mvc 5 project and i need to connect the C# values for my width.For example if my composion capacity is 100,and i insert 30 i want the second progressive's bar width to be composionCapacity + Quantity i entered (0+30),all that is generated from database

```
<style>
#FirstProgressBar 
{
    background-color: black;
    border-radius:13px;
    padding:3px;
    width:300px;
}
#SecondProgressBar {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius:20px;
    width: 25px;
    height:15px;
}
```

Comment: Please show your server side code and explain what you want to achieve, what you have now, and what the difference between actual and expected results. Side note: 'Progressive bar' is kind of pub interested in change and progress?

Comment: I have 3 operations controllers made with entity framework -> Compositions Products Operations,my point is when i create a operation is that my progressive bar is to show the quantity in the composition

Comment: Kiril, sorry, but still no edits in your question. Use *edit* link under question body

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is within a razor view, you can add the values for composionCapacity and Quantity to YourViewModel, and then:

```
@model YourViewModel

<style>
    #SecondProgressBar {
        background-color: orange;
        border-radius:20px;
        width: @(Model.ComposionCapacity + Model.Quantity)px;
        height:15px;
    }
</style>
```